# Model instance not saving

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am writing a post request for a DRF APIView and testing it. The Tagging object appears in the browser, however when I look into the django admin it's simply not there. The Gamerounds and Gamesessions are getting saved however.

Did I maybe forget to do something here?

**views.py**

```
...
        if not isinstance(request.user, CustomUser):
            current_user_id = 1
        else:
            current_user_id = request.user.pk
        score = 0

        gamesession = Gamesession.objects.create(user_id=current_user_id,
                                                 gametype=Gametype.objects.all().order_by('?').first(),
                                                 created=datetime.now())
        gameround = Gameround.objects.create(user_id=current_user_id,
                                             gamesession=gamesession,
                                             created=datetime.now(),
                                             score=score)
        random_resource = Resource.objects.all().order_by('?').first()

        # A previously played gameround for this resource is coordinated for Tag verification
        controller = GameViewController()
        coordinated_gameround = controller.get_gameround_matching_resource(random_resource.id)

        origin = ''
        user_input_tag = Tag.objects.create(name='new tag obj', language='de')
        tag_serializer = TagSerializer(user_input_tag)

        if Tagging.objects.all().filter(tag=user_input_tag).exists():
            # if tagging like this exists, save tagging anyway and leave tag unchanged
            score += 5
            user_input_tagging = Tagging.objects.update_or_create(user_id=current_user_id,
                                                                  gameround=gameround,
                                                                  resource=random_resource,
                                                                  tag=user_input_tag,
                                                                  created=datetime.now(),
                                                                  score=score,
                                                                  origin=origin)

            tagging_serializer = TaggingSerializer(user_input_tagging)

            return Response({'tag and ': tag_serializer.data}, {'tagging': tagging_serializer.data})

        elif not Tagging.objects.all().filter(tag=user_input_tag).exists():
            # save tagging otherwise and del tag
            user_input_tagging = Tagging.objects.create(user_id=current_user_id,
                                                        gameround=gameround,
                                                        resource=random_resource,
                                                        tag=user_input_tag,
                                                        created=datetime.now(),
                                                        score=score,
                                                        origin=origin)
            user_input_tagging.save()
            tagging_serializer = TaggingSerializer(user_input_tagging)
            user_input_tag.delete()
            return Response({'tagging only': tagging_serializer.data})
```

Comment: If you can see it in the browser, I expect it to be saved into the DB. This leads most probably to the fact that your admin interface is not properly set? Btw: You do not need to run user_input_tagging.save() as the object was already created with .create() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create

Comment: I thought save() would help. But I refreshed the admin interface countless times. The Gamerounds for example are saved it's just the tagging that's problematic. Could it be that it's saved but then because I need to delete the Tag object my Tagging is also deleted?

Comment: Yes, the tag will be deleted immediately after it was created.

Comment: Is there a way to save the Tagging without keeping the Tag?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean if I only want to create a Tag as soon as it has been entered as a Tagging twice - what is the correct approach here?